# Add custom category attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm tryng to create a custom category attribute using this [guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html) but it doesn't work for me, this is the code that I'm using for the 
InstallData.php:

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
  private $eavSetupFactory;

  public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
  }

  public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
  {
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'disposizione', [
        'type'     => 'int',
        'label'    => 'Disposizione',
        'input'    => 'boolean',
        'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
        'visible'  => true,
        'default'  => '0',
        'required' => false,
        'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'group'    => 'Display Settings',
    ]);
  }
}
```

category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="display_settings">
    <field name="disposizione">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Nome Produttore</item>
                <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                </item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Ng_AddAttribute" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
  'Ng_AddAttribute',
  __DIR__
);
```

[image: Schermata_2018-08-07_alle_18.48.29.png]

After that i upgrade the schema with `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and clear the cache, but a error appears when i reload the page:
`Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document in Entity`
this is only a try, I need to create two attribute one text and one select.
could someone help me

**EDIT:**

I've resolved the XML problem and now i can see the field in the backend but it didn't save the data.

Comment: Please check this, are you wanted like below picture. https://prnt.sc/kfuq3a

Comment: Yes, first I need a text field for an additional name and than I need to create a select field with 2 options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like there is something wrong with XML or setup version in your files.

Your Xml file should start from line one.

run below command

```
php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Ng_AddAttribute
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Ok, I've resolved the XML problem and now i can see the field in the backend but it didn't save the data.